# How to combined rows based on multiple field's value?

Tags: sql, vba

Need support,

I have a table in Access with huge number of records.
I would like to run a query which can shorten the data.

Example:

`Table name : Lux1`

```
+-----------+--------+------+
|Invoice No.|Fee Type|Amount|
+-----------+--------+------+
|18903      |D&R     |30    |
+-----------+--------+------+
|18903      |D&R     |40    |
+-----------+--------+------+
|27035      |Others  |100   |
+-----------+--------+------+
|27035      |Others  |75    |
+-----------+--------+------+
```

Expected table: (Combined the invoice field based on Fee type criteria)

```
+-----------+--------+------+
|Invoice No.|Fee Type|Amount|
+-----------+--------+------+
|18903      |D&R     |70    |
+-----------+--------+------+
|27035      |Others  |175   |
+-----------+--------+------+
```

Can somebody help me to achieve this objective via SQL statement or any other method?

Comment: suppose in the above table there is one more column called Client Name, however i want to group by only Invoice no. and FeeType, how to write SQL statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 INSERT NEWTABLE(InvoiceNo,FeeType,Amount)
 SELECT InvoiceNo,
        FeeType,
        SUM(Amount)
 FROM SourceTable
 GROUP BY InvoiceNo,
          FeeType
```

Comment: Hi i stuck at one place, suppose in the above table there is one more column called Client Name, however i want to group by only Invoice no. and FeeType, how to write SQL statement?

Comment: you would have to include it in the SELECT and the GROUP BY

Comment: are there more than 1 client name for the same invoice?

Answer (score 0):

```
select InvNo, FeeType, sum(Amount) as Amount
from MyTable
group by InvNo, FeeType
```

Comment: Hi i stuck at one place, suppose in the above table there is one more column called Client Name, however i want to group by only Invoice no. and FeeType, how to write SQL statement?